# Using Siri for commercial purposes?

Tags: siri, license

Does anyone know what the rules are on using Siri for unintended purposes?  I would like to actually hook it up to my company's phone number so that when someone calls in, I can have them routed to Siri.

Questions of how this would work technically aside, are there any Apple terms-of-use that say this isn't allowed?

Comment: It's probably a violation of the non-commercial usage agreement you enter into when you license the software, but I can't find anywhere in the SLA that says it outright.  IANAL, and I suggest you consult one before spending time developing this idea.  In my mind, it would involve quite a lot of setup for something that might be easier using a PBX.

Comment: http://www.rememberthemilk.com/services/siri/ Someone has in a sort of round about way. But like bmike has said there is no public API, unfortunately, for Siri. And considering how long it's been I wouldn't expect to see it anytime soon.

Answer (score 1):

Since Apple doesn't offer an API to use their Siri services, you might be limited to coming up with some [Rube Goldberg machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rube_Goldberg_machine) that presses the home button of your iPhone and rubs a buddha belly for luck (or whatever else you desire to have happen simultaneously with the incoming call) so that Siri will work at the exact moment your caller is speaking to her.

Again, there is no API to do anything except listen to what Siri responds sonically so it's not clear how this might be useful for anything but a fun youtube video.

Now, your business might very well be able to [license a voice like Siri](http://techcrunch.com/2011/10/05/apple-siri-nuance/) (or the same exact voice for enough $$) by contacting [Nuance](http://www.nuance.com) or some other computer speech vendor - but their product likely won't run on iOS since other custom hardware is likely to be more capable for an automated PBX.